# прием строки символов из последовательного порта

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, serial

Это не курсач и не диплом! Я давно уже не студент. Это попытка написать еще одну бесплатную прогу для "домашней" диагностики автомобилей. И я не очень силен в Питоне. Поэтому прошу помощи.

**Исходные данные:**

Имеется некоторое устройство, которое подключено к компу через USB-порт. Комп и устройство обмениваются данными в символьном виде. По сути, это классическое соединение: устройство -- играет роль сервера, а комп -- роль терминала. Если кому-то что-то это скажет, то это устройство -- это адаптер OBD-II (On-Board Diagnostics -- устройство для диагности автомобилей) ELM327.

Система работает по очень простому принципу -- на запрос (команду) клиента (терминала), сервер возвращает ответ. Вот пример запроса-ответа:

```
> ati
ELM327 v1.5

> atdp
AUTO, ISO 15765-4 (CAN 11/250)
```

Вот так выглядит строка ответа "ELM327 v1.5" в hex виде:

```
45 4C 4D 33 32 37 20 76 31 2E 35 0D 0D 3E
```

А так строка ответа "AUTO, ISO 15765-4 (CAN 11/250)":

```
41 55 54 4F 2C 20 49 53 4F 20 31 35 37 36 35 2D 34 20 28 43 41 4E 20 31 31 2F 32 35 30 29 0D 0D 3E
```

Во первых, в строке ответа вместо символа '\n' используется символ '\r'. (Тут нет проблемы. Это легко исправляется.) Во вторых, ответ заканчивается симвлом '>' (hex-код = 0x3E), что приводит к усложнению программного кода обработки ответа. Тут тоже нет неразрешимой проблемы.

Проблема, которую я не могу одолеть, заключается в том, что в Питоне-3 я не могу толком получить из порта строку символов. В Питоне-2.7 запрос-ответ работает без проблем.

Вот код для второго Питона:

```
def show_response(port):
  while True:
    resp = ''
    while True:
      ch = port.read(1)
      if len(ch) == 1:
        # print ch
        if ch == '\r':
          resp += '\n'
        else:
          resp += ch

      if resp[-2:] == '\n>':
        print resp[:-2],
        break
```

Для третьего Питона это код (поняное дело!) не подходит. Я не имею в виду замену оператора print для Питон-2 на функцию print() для Питон-3. Это всё легко правится.

Проблема -- в приёме данных от последовательного порта. Если во втором Питоне достаточно сделать (упрощенно говоря) так:

```
ch = port.read(1)
print ch
```

, то в третьем Питоне функция read() возвращает не строку символов, а строку байт.

Я -- Си-шник. И для меня байт-- от и в Африке байт. С моей точки зрения -- что байт, что ASCII-символ (не многобайтовые символы типа utf-8!!!, а именно одно-байтовый ASCII-символ из первой половины таблицы кодов)  -- это один и тот же набор битов. Поэтому функция read() в модуле serial для второго Питона, возвращающая строку символов, и функция read() в модуле serial для третьего Питона, возвращающая строку байт, -- должны давать одинаковый результат.

Но на практике вместо строки байт "45 4C 4D 33 32 ..." (ответ на команду ati во втором Питоне), в третьем Питоне я получаю всего три байта "7F BF ED". И более уже ничего не могу получить. Обмен между ELM327 и компом происходит байтами (символами ?), находящимися в диапазоне 0..0x7F. Ни какой кириллицей и не пахнет! Откуда такие странные коды -- 0xBF и 0xED ?

Что я делаю не так?

Вот код для третьего Питона:

```
def show_response(port):
  #print('show_response')
  while True:
    resp = ''
    while True:
      b = port.read(1)
  if len(b) != 0:
    print('0x{0:02X}'.format(b[0]))
    #if ch == '\r':
    #  resp += '\n'
    #else:
    #  resp += ch

  if resp[-2:] == '\n>':
    print(resp[:-2], end='')
    break
```

Инициализация порта для второго и третьего Питона практически одинаковая:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#coding:utf8

import serial
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 38400, timeout=0.2)
  except serial.SerialException:
    print('Соединение не удалось')
    exit(1)

  port.flushOutput()
  port.flushInput()

  p1 = Process(target=show_response, args=(port,))
  p1.daemon = True
  p1.start()
  command(port)
  print('Пока-пока!')
```

Пакет serial устанавливал из стандартных репозиториев -- на одном компе (Ubuntu-10.04) это была уставнока пакета для второго Питона ($ sudo apt-get install python-serial), на другом компе (Debian-8) -- для третьего Питона (# apt-get install python3-serial).

Не понимаю, куда копать? Кто-нибудь выпишите мне волшебный пендель в нужном направлении, а то ведь так и помру, не поняв сути Питоновских махинаций с байтами.

**UPDATE 08.08.2015 - 00:53**

Я изменил прогу, благо она вообще микроскопическая. Сейчас тупо открывается порт, тупо дается команда девасу -- 'ati\r' и тупо выводится на консоль всё, что сыплется из порта в ответ на эту команду -- никаких процессов, никаких ухищрений, ничего лишнего! И тем не менее результат вывода на консоль точно такой же.

Вот текст этой проги:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#coding:utf8

import serial
import time


if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 38400, timeout=1)
  except serial.SerialException:
    print('Соединение не удалось')
    exit(1)

  port.flushOutput()
  port.flushInput()

  # Послать запрос
  cmd = bytes('ati\r', 'utf-8')
  port.write(cmd)

  time.sleep(0.1)

  # Принять ответ и вывести его на консоль
  while True:
    print('.')

    resp = port.readline()

    # Вариант вывода 1
    if len(resp) > 0:
      print('[{0:d}] = '.format(len(resp)), end = '')
      for b in resp:
        print('0x{0:02X} '.format(b), end='')

    '''
    # Вариант вывода 2
    string = str(port.readline())
    if len(string) > 0:
      print('[{0:d}] = '.format(len(string)), end = '')
      for ch in string:
        print('0x{0:02X} '.format(ord(ch)), end='')
    '''

    '''
    # Вариант вывода 3
    string = str(port.readline())
    if len(string) > 0:
      print('[{0:d}] = '.format(len(string)), end = '')
      print(string)
   '''
```

Вывод по первому варианту такой (скриншот):

```
$ ./myOBDm2.py
.
[2] = 0x7F 0xBF .
.
.
.
```

Вывод по второму варианту -- такой:

```
$ ./myOBDm2.py
.
[3] = 0x62 0x27 0x27 .
[3] = 0x62 0x27 0x27 .
[3] = 0x62 0x27 0x27 .
[3] = 0x62 0x27 0x27 .
[3] = 0x62 0x27 0x27 .
[3] = 0x62 0x27 0x27 .
```

Вывод по третьему варианту -- такой:

```
$ ./myOBDm2.py
.
[3] = b''
.
[3] = b''
.
[3] = b''
.
```

Более детальное изучение вывода по третьему варианту намекает, что функция readline() возвращает пустую строку байтов -- ведь три символа **b''** -- это ничто иное как строка байтов в Питоне. Интересно, чтобы это значило? Почему serial в Питон-3 так странно работает?

Также я пробовал перебирать варианты кодировок при посылке запроса:

```
  # Послать запрос
  cmd = bytes('ati\r', 'utf-8') # 'cp866', 'cp1251', 'ascii'
  port.write(cmd)
```

Ничего не менялось, кодировка никак не влияет.

На девайсе есть светодиода, которые моргают при приёме и передаче данных по USB-интерфейсу. Судя по морганию -- обмен идёт.

**UPDATE 08.08.2015 - 16:47**

Я сделал два изменения в проге:

```
...
  # Послать запрос
  cmd = bytes('ati\r\n', 'ascii')  # -1- Добавил '\n'
  port.write(cmd)

  time.sleep(1)

  # Принять ответ и вывести его на консоль
  while True:
    print('.')

    resp = port.read()    # -2- Изменил функцию (была readline)

    # Вариант вывода 1
    if len(resp) > 0:
      print('[{0:d}] = '.format(len(resp)), end = '')
      for b in resp:
        print('0x{0:02X} '.format(b), end='')

...
```

В результате на консоль получил правильный результат:

```
$ ./myOBDm2.py
.
[1] = 0x61 .
[1] = 0x74 .
[1] = 0x69 .
[1] = 0x0D .
[1] = 0x45 .
[1] = 0x4C .
[1] = 0x4D .
[1] = 0x33 .
[1] = 0x32 .
[1] = 0x37 .
[1] = 0x20 .
[1] = 0x76 .
[1] = 0x31 .
[1] = 0x2E .
[1] = 0x35 .
[1] = 0x0D .
[1] = 0x0D .
[1] = 0x3E .
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Но рапортовать о решении проблемы рано, так как проблема исчезляа только для первого (после включения компа) запуска проги. Повтороное и все последующие запуски проги выдавали одинаковые неправильные результаты:

```
$ ./myOBDm2.py
.
[1] = 0x7F .
[1] = 0xBF .
[1] = 0xFE .
.
.
.
.
```

Следует заметить, что при возврате ответа от девайса, строки заканчиваются
символом '\r', а не '\n' и не их комбинацией '\r\n'.

По моим представлениям девайс игнорирует символ '\n'. В описании вообще-то сказано, что девайс игнорирует также и другие "белые" символы (пробел, табуляция, ..). Например, девайс одинково правильно понимает команды 'ati\r' и 'at i\r'.

Таким образом наличие или отсутствие в конце команда символа '\n' никак не влияет на работоспособность девайса, что и подтверждается на практике.

**UPDATE 08.08.2015 - 19:31**

Хорошо. Перезагружаю комп и смотрю на настройки порта. Настройки порта перед запуском программы следующие:

```
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0
speed 57600 baud; line = 0;
eof = ^A; min = 1; time = 0;
-brkint -icrnl -imaxbel
-opost -onlcr
-icanon -echo -echoe
```

Затем запускаю прогу. Она отрабатывает нормально. Выхожу из проги, и снова смотрю настройки порта:

```
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
eof = ^A; min = 0; time = 0;
-brkint -icrnl -imaxbel
-opost -onlcr
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke
```

Оп-па! Что называется -- "Найди семь отличий!"

Методом перебора включения/выключения настроек порта (точнее сказать -- порта_терминала), удалось обнаружить, что "мешается" параметр **-iexten**.

Если перед запуском проги выключить этот параметр

```
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 iexten
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0
  speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
    eof = ^A; min = 0; time = 0;
    -brkint -icrnl -imaxbel
    -opost -onlcr
    -isig -icanon -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke
```

, то прога снова нормально отрабатывает.

Иначе говоря, модуль serial в Python-3 при открытие порта меняет его настройки. Модуль serial в Python-2 точно так же меняет настройки порта, но здесь (во втором Питоне) эти настройки не приводят к фатальным последствиям.

Теперь осталось найти способ, как при открытии порта в модуле serial для Python-3 указать, что параметр **IEXTEN** не нужно устанавливать.

Проблема все еще не решена. Продолжаю копать. По мере "лечения" буду публиковать свои шаги.

**UPDATE от 28.08.2015-02:01**

В результате неспешных попыток заставить девайс ELM327 работать под Питоном-3, я пришел к пониманию, что возможно это не Питон не способен принять ответ от девайса, а наоборот -- Питон не способен передать девайсц команду. Точнее так: Питон передает искаженную команду, девай получает хрен-знает-что и выдает Питону ответ типа "я не понимаю". Поскольку, Питон работает не правильно, то и ответ он тоже понимает в искаженном виде. Косвенным подтверждением этому является то, что через 30 скунд девас отправляет в комп какую-то короткую "отрыжку". Я предположил, что это может быть что-то типа "незаконченная команда снимается по тайм-ауту". По крайней мере такого явления ("отрыжки") при работе под Питоном-2 не наблюдается. Другими словами, Питон-2 посылает в девайс правильную команду, а Питон-3 искаженную. Соответственно девас так и реагирует.

Что бы проверить то, что Питон-3 посылает бессмыслицу, я поставил несложный (для электронщиков, а я -- электронщик) эксперимент. Я взял два китайских конвертера USB-UART типа CH340G и соединил их по схеме нуль-модема. Затем, подключил один к рабочему компу, на котором прога крутится под Питон-3, а другой к нотиику, на котором точно такая же (ну, за исключением print и некоторых других отличий) прога крутится под Питон-2.

Тогда, если Питон-3 искажает команды, я увижу эти искажения на втором компе.

Да! Существенное дополнение -- в девайсе ELM-327 используется микросхема конвертера CH340T, это клон CH340G.

В результате я увидел, что при передаче данных в обоих направдлениях никаких искажений нет и в помине! Пробовал на разных скоростях обмена. Все работает чётко. Отсюда вывод -- проблемы в связке девайса и Питона-3.

Устройство ELM327 -- неразборное, чем-то напоминает блоки питания для нотиков. Пришлось крушить корпус молотком. Вскрыл более-менее нормально.

А вот далее начинается вторая серия детектива.

Я подключил осциллограф к выходу UART-а микросхемы CH340T, чтобы посмотреть, что она передает непосредственно в микроконтроллер.

Держитесь за стул! Оказывается, что микросхема передает правильные данные, но не на той скорости, какую мы ожидаем. Точнее так, в питоновской программе при инициализации последовательного порта указывается скорость работы. Программа, работающая под Питон-2, настраивает микросхему CH340T на заданную скорость. А вот программа, работающая под Питон-3, по какой-то неведомой причине не может настроить эту микросхему. В результате получается, что прога из-под Питона-2 обращается к микроконтроллеру на скорости 38400, а прога из-под Питона-3 -- на скорости 9600 Бод.

Микроконтроллер ожидает, что к нему будут "стучаться" на 38400, и по этому он, естественно, не правильно понимает команду от компа. Далее микроконтроллер выдает ответ типа "Вы что там, совсем охренели?" на скорости 38400, но CH340T принимает это на скорости 9600 и передает в комп мусор. А через 30 секунд микрконтроллер посылает в комп еще один пакет типа "Да ну вас нахрен! Эту команду я снимаю. Вводите следующую!".

Теперь мне нужно понять -- почему Питон-3 не способен правильно проинициализировать микросхему конвертера CH340T.

**UPDATE от 28.08.2015-04:05**

Скажу сразу -- проблему победить не удалось, но удалось нащупать "обходной путь". Рецепт прост -- в Питоне-3 не следует производить одновременно инициализацию порта и установку скорости.

Так делать не надо:

```
  try:
    port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 38400, timeout=0.2)
  except serial.SerialException:
    print('Соединение не удалось')
    exit(1)
```

Следует делать так:

```
  try:
    port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0")
    port.baudrate = 38400
    port.timeout = 0.2
  except serial.SerialException:
    print('Соединение не удалось')
    exit(1)
```

Я так понимаю, что это накосячено где-то в конструкторе класса Serial. Но заниматься ремонтом этого дурдома меня что-то больше не прёт.

Comment: 1. я бы для начала попробовал общаться **без** создания процесса. 2. посмотрите, например, как [здесь](http://www.scienceprog.com/reading-serial-data-from-chipkit-uno32-using-python3-and-pyserial/) реализовано чтение из последовательного порта.

Comment: Спасибо, что откликнулись и попытались предложитиь варианты.

Comment: вы обратили внимание, что в примере, ссылку на который я привёл, при чтении используется функция `decode()`? `line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')[:-2]`

Comment: 1. Вам возможно нужно `b'\r\n'` вместо `b'\r'`(терминалы даже на Unix используют `\r\n` как конец строки 2. `flush()` или подобное не помешает 3. Используйте `print(b)` для отладки (`bytes` константу покажет) 4. `.readline()` на бинарном потоке читает пока `b'\n'` не встретится, можно вместо этого `b = port.read(100, timeout=1)` использовать.5. Что происходит, если запустить пример `miniterm.py` и ручками команды вбивать? 6. *"кодировка никак не влияет."* -- это потому что все байты в примере в ascii диапазоне и все приведённые кодировки одинаковы в этом диапазоне.

Comment: Следует отличать двоичные данные (байты) от текста (Unicode): `unicode_text = bytestring.decode(encoding);` `bytestring = unicode_text.encode(encoding)`

Comment: `binascii.hexlify(b"b''") == b'622727'`, то есть первое что надо сделать это убрать все `str()` вызовы в Вашем скрипте. Если `readline()` возвращает `b''` это либо `EOF` (конец), либо (в сломанных реализациях) `EAGAIN` (для non-blocking файлов) (нет данных сейчас). Обычно если `read()` возвращает `b''`, то ничто другое он уже больше не вернёт никогда.

Comment: @jts, спасибо за участие в решении проблемы. Смотрите новые подробности в подновление, которое я дописал в вопросе. 1. Добавление символа '\n' к команде никак не влияет на работоспособность. 2. Про декодинг на данный момент можно даже не говорить -- serial ничего не возвращает -- декодировать нечего! 3. У меня такое ощущение, что что-то не то происходит в модуле serial. Он как-то не так настраивает его терминал. У меня есть определенное желание перевести этот модуль-терминал в режим raw, чтобы он не вмешивался в поток получаемых байт. Но как это сделать -- я не знаю.

Comment: @ЖевакАлександрАнтонович, «чтобы не вмешивался» — это, вероятно, про *flow-control*. по идее, эти настройки можно указать при вызове функции `serial()` (или ещё какой-нибудь функции из этого модуля), уточните в документаци к модулю. ещё я бы рекомендовал понизить скорость обмена, но тут надо уточнять в документации к устройству — какие скорости работы последовательного порта оно поддерживает.

Comment: @alexander-barakin: Скорость у девайса либо такая не совсем привычная -- 38400, по умолчанию, либо 9600 (нужно дать команду). Но скорость вряд ли как-то повлияет на результат, так как обмен идет по USB, а реальная UART-передача -- по плате устройства, по проводничкам в несколько сантиметров длиной. (Но я и эту версию тоже проверю.) Другое дело, что в Python-2 всё работает, а в Python-3 такие залипухи.

Comment: текущий формат у вопроса не слишком удачный. Старайтесь ограничиваться *одной*  проблемой на вопрос. Иначе он почти бесполезен для других участников. У Вас несколько независимых проблем: (1) не понимание разницы между obj vs. repr(obj) vs. str(obj) и почему `.format()` здесь не нужен  (2) настройка конца строки (обычно  `readline()` для binary потоков только `b'\n'` понимает) (3) `read()` читает до конца (EOF) не имеет смысла более одного раза вызывать (4) как tty настройки указать через `serial` интерфейс. Чудес не бывает: запустите python2 и python3 под `strace` и посмотрите разницу.

Comment: @jfs: (1)"текущий формат у вопроса не слишком удачный." -- Да, я это вижу. Но что делать с таким форматом -- я не знаю. Я совсем недавно пришел на этот ресурс. Толком еще не освоился. (2) Да, действительно, я смутно понимаю эти вещи. Я -- си-шник, и мое си-шное мировозрение не приемлет некоторые Питоновские приемы. Но разницу между read() и readline() я понимаю. Другое дело, что у меня уже истерика и я начал тупо перебирать все варианты с целью найти хоть какую-нибудь зацепку. (3) Спасибо за уделенное мне время и науку!

Answer (score 2):

Похожая ситуация на Pyton2
при приеме информации с тестера UT60D, который только передает сигналы в порт.

При открытии порта в рекомендованных настройках, на входе порта +10 вольт и пачки сигналов пропадают.

Помогло:

**ser.rtsToggle=True**

Comment: Спасибо за попытку помочь. К сожалению, не помогло. Вообще никак не повлияло -- ни True, ни False.

Comment: Могу рекомендовать посмотреть напряжение на входе порта. Нормально -10 вольт и импульсы до +10 вольт.

Comment: К сожалению, Виталий, это не то.

Comment: Устройство представляет собой наглухо заваренную коробочку, которую нельзя открыть не разрушив её. С одной строны коробочка имеет разъем, с помощью которого на присоединяется к бортовой сети автомобиля. На разъем выведены контакты: Общего провода, Питание +12В, два контакта CAN-шины и еще какие-то. С другой стороны у коробочки находится неотключаемый от неё провод USB. Внутри коробочки, CAN-сигналы с бортовой сетb автомобиля обрабатываются встроенным микроконтроллером, который на выходе выдает сигналы UART. UART это не RS232! Отличаются они друг от друга уровнями напржения и полярностью логики

Comment: Далее сигналы UART подаются на микросхему конвертера UART-USB. Так что, с одной строны, внутри коробки однозначно нет ни каких 10-вольтовых сигналов, тем более минусовой полярности. С другой стороны, я пока не хочу ломать коробку. Есть и третий довод -- дело в том, что с Питон-2 таких проблем не наблюдается. Это однозначно глюк Питона-3, точнее его модуля -- serial. Я скажу больше! Я тут заметил, что во второй Питон отравляет команду в коробку и принимает от нее ответ за один раз, после такой транзакции наступает тишина (пауза) до посылки следующей команды.

Comment: Третий же Питон посылает команду, тут же получает невнятный ответ тх 2-3 байт (то о чем я писал в своем вопросе), а потом через 30 секунд коробочка досылает еще один байт. Отсюда я делаю предположение, так может быть я не там ищу? Может быть нужно проверять не приём, а вообще передачу? Может быть Питон-3 что-то не то засылает в коробку? Например, засылает назавешенную команду. Коробка сначала отвечает каким-то пакетом типа "Не понимаю", а через тридцать секунд присылает еще один пакет типа "ты будешь вообще завершать команду?" или "незавершенная команда откинута по тайм-ауту".

Comment: Но это нужно проверять. Чем я сейчас и занимаюсь. Виталий, тем не менее, я благодарен Вам за Ваше участие в разрешении проблемы!

Comment: Извиняюсь, USB просмотрел.

Comment: На предмет приема и передачи. На Python2 блокируется прием в буфер во время передачи. (Для COM появляется +10 вольт на втором контакте разъема). Справка по pySerial http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html.

Comment: Ух ты! Не знал. Это что получается? Это значит, что второй Питон на последовательном порту может работать только в режиме симплекса?То есть прием и передача в одно и то же время невозможны. Надо будет еще повнимательней перепочитать справку. И тем временем я все=таки вскрыл черепушку девайсу. см. UPDATE в вовпросе. Там вообще детективная история разворачивается.

Comment: В теории настройки должны помочь. Собственно у меня выход порта используется для подзаряда батареек или для включения более мощного источника. На MatLab и VBA можно спокойно считывать из буфера измерения и во время заряда батарейки. При блокировке принимался только один байт с нулевым кодом (ord).  Предположительно это принимался фронт блокирующего импульса.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27489/discussion-between-vitaly-lysanov-and---).

Comment: В общем-то, Витлий, я не против переноса обсуждения в чат. Какая разница где разговаривать! Другое дело, что в данный момент я чате я не могу ничего писать. Думаю, что для чата нужно завести еще один аккаунт. Сейчас мне не очень удобно разбираться еще и сэтой заморочкой. У нас уже четыре часа утра, у меня уже все плывет перед глазами. Давайте до завтра, а?

Comment: Предложение перенести обсуждение в чат РЕКОМЕНДОВАЛИ. Для подробностей могу предложить vitalij.lysanov@yandex.ru

Answer (score 0):

Для корректной отправки символов в порт помог вариант с отправкой `\r` перед основными командами

```
ser.write(b'\rCR;CS\r')
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

lsusb:
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter
cat /proc/version:
Linux version 3.19.0-84-generic


мне помогла установка 'echo' перед каждым запуском программы на питоне

stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 cs8 -parenb -cstopb raw **echo**